# Clojure futures mysteriously dying

Tags: multithreading, clojure

I have an application that spins up a number of futures to do prolonged work. It's intermittently failing and I'm trying to work out why.

The symptom is that the code is just ceasing to execute, and stops in a random place. My future-creation-code is something like this:

```
(def future-timeout
 ; 1 hour
 3600000)

(def concurrency 200)


(defn do-parallel
  [f coll]
  (let [chunks (partition-all concurrency coll)]
    (doseq [chunk chunks]
      (let [futures (doall
                      (map #(future
                              (try
                                (f %)
                              (catch Exception e
                                (log/error "Unhandled error in do-parallel:" (.getMessage e))
                                :exception)))
                           chunk))
            results (doall (map #(deref % future-timeout :timeout) futures))
            all-ok (every? true? results)]

      (when all-ok
        (log/info "Chunk successful."))

      (when-not all-ok
        (log/error "Chunk unsuccessful.")
        (log/warn "Parallel execution results:" results))

      (swap! chunk-count inc)))
  (log/info "Finished batch")))
```

The concurrency variable controls the size of batches, and therefore the number of concurrent executions it attempts. `f` returns `true` on success. If there's a timeout or exception, they return `:timeout` or `:exception`.

I'm doing this instead of `pmap` because I want to control concurrency, `f` is a long-running (~10 minutes), network-intensive task. `pmap` seems to be tuned toward mid-sized, smaller batches.

Normally this works fine. But after a few hours it stops:

- During the execution of `f`, the function stops running.
- No exception is caught. No timeout occurs.
- The loop in `do-parallel` stops and no more log entries appear.
- Other threads, e.g. Kafka Client, keep running.

Any ideas of what might be causing this? Or steps to put in place to help diagnose?

Comment: You may also want to view Claypoole for parallel tasks:  https://github.com/TheClimateCorporation/claypoole

Comment: Cheers, that looks like a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try to install an uncaught exception handler, to see if a stray exception on the `Executor` itself is causing work to stop.

https://github.com/pyr/uncaught has a facility for this, but it's also straightforward to do from the code directly.

Comment: Thanks! I do actually have setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler running.

Comment: The UncaughtExceptionHandler does not work for `future` the way it works for `Thread.`. With `future` another approach is necessary, e.g. `try`/`catch` inside the body.

Answer (score 0):

[Claypool](https://github.com/TheClimateCorporation/claypoole) is useful for controlling parallelism.

```
(cp/pmap (count chunk) f chunk)
```

will create a temporary threadpool the same size as your chunk and execute all the functions in parallel.

This is just a suggestion for expressing parallelism, not an answer to your question which is about error handling; which I'm curious about also!

Comment: Thanks, it can't hurt to try that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try catch Throwable instead of Exception? I've had issues before that slipped through catch Exception because of it.

I think if there's an uncaught exception in the futures, it catches it and dies without throwing it further out, so setting the default uncaughtexception isn't going to help. Untested - but that's my gut feel.

Do you get the "Chunk unsuccessful" message at the end at least, when it stops? because if you don't, then that's really weird...

Looking around the implementation of `future` - it uses a cachedthreadpool underneath - which doesn't have a thread limit, so you're probably better off using the ExecutorService directly, or something like [claypoole](https://github.com/TheClimateCorporation/claypoole), like the other suggestions indicate.

Comment: When the bug occurs, there's no "Chunk successful" or "Chunk unsuccessful". Yes, it's very weird. Weirder still, some observable outputs suggest that the code gets further than its logs indicate. I wonder if it's a per-thread log buffer not getting flushed... Thanks for the Throwable tip, that may account for something. I think using Claypool is the obvious first step.

Comment: Agree, try changing to Throwable first.